# How to Convert varchar time to Time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have `decimal` time and I am able to convert into `time`. However I need to insert converted time into a table which has a column of `time` datatype

```
DECLARE @hours decimal(15,4)
SELECT @hours = 20.5 //20 Hrs and 30 mins

SELECT    
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(@hours)), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(((@hours - FLOOR(@hours)) * 60))), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(((@hours - FLOOR(@hours)) * 60) - FLOOR(((@hours - FLOOR(@hours)) * 60))) * 60), 2) AS Time
```

This is my temp table that I need to insert the value into:

```
create table #timetest(timetest time)

insert into #timetest
  SELECT    
      RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(@hours)), 2) + ':' +
      RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(((@hours - FLOOR(@hours)) * 60))), 2) + ':'   +
      RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(((@hours - FLOOR(@hours)) * 60) - FLOOR(((@hours - FLOOR(@hours)) * 60))) * 60), 2)
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Please help me

Comment: I believe you cannot have `TIME` values for more than 24 hours ....

Comment: You can do `cast(@hours/24 as datetime)` but for `28.5` that will give you the time `04:30:00.0000000` which is not what you want I guess.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have changed my time also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @hours decimal(15,4)

set @hours = 20.5 --20 Hrs and 30 mins

create table #timetest(timetest time(0))

insert into #timetest(timetest) values(cast(@hours/24 as datetime))

select * from #timetest

drop table #timetest
```

Result:

```
20:30:00
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you cannot have `TIME` values for more than 24 hours ....

Check the [MSDN documentation on `TIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx):

> *Range    00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999*

**Update:** if you've changed your time to less than 24 hours, you can do the insert like this:

```
create table #timetest(timetest time)

insert into #timetest(timetest)
  SELECT     
     CAST(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(@hours)), 2) + ':' +
          RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(((@hours - FLOOR(@hours)) * 60))), 2) + ':'   +
          RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(((@hours - FLOOR(@hours)) * 60) - FLOOR(((@hours - FLOOR(@hours)) * 60))) * 60), 2) AS TIME)
```

You need to explicitly `CAST` your string `AS TIME` and then everything should work just fine.